# Characterization of non uniformly b0unded sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\{f_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N} }$ be a sequence of functions $f_n:I\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$ where $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ interval.

A sequence of function is not uniformly bounded if $\forall K > 0$ there exist $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+, t\in I$ such that $\|f_n(t)\| > K$.

I'm looking for a characterization in terms of sequences.

I can see that if $f_n$ is bounded for each $n$ then these two are equivalent:

1.there exists $t_n\in I$ with $\lim_n\|f_n(t_n)\| \rightarrow +\infty$

2.the sequence is not uniformly bounded.

Comment: Strictly speaking 1. is not equivalent to 2. Consider $f_n(t)=1$ if $n$ is odd and $f_n(t)=n$ if $n$ is even. It becomes correct if you select a subsequence first, i.e. $f_n$ is not uniformely bounded if and only if there exists a subsequence $(f_{n_m})$ and $t_{n_m}\in I$, such that $\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty} \|f_{n_m}(t_{n_m})\|=\infty$

Comment: Alternatively, you could use $\limsup$ instead of $\lim$.